# function usage and output of lapply

Tags: r

I am trying to play with function of `lapply`

```
lapply(1:3, function(i) print(i))
# [1] 1
# [1] 2
# [1] 3
# [[1]]
# [1] 1

# [[2]]
# [1] 2

# [[3]]
# [1] 3
```

I understand that `lapply` should be able to perform `print (i)` against each element `i`  among `1:3`
But why the output looks like this.

Besides, when I use `unlist`, I get the output like the following

```
unlist(lapply(1:3, function(i) print(i)))
# [1] 1
# [1] 2
# [1] 3
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: yes, you get the printout and afterwards the object that is returned is printed implicitly. If you save the output in an object you will not see the second part. `l <- lapply(1:5, function(x) print(i))`

Comment: Please do not use images to represent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of lapply function is the following:

**"lapply returns a list of the same length as X, each element of which is the result of applying FUN to the corresponding element of X."**

Your example:

```
lapply(1:3, function(x) print(x))
```

Prints the object x and returns a list of length 3.

```
str(lapply(1:3, function(x) print(x)))
# [1] 1
# [1] 2
# [1] 3
# List of 3
# $ : int 1
# $ : int 2
# $ : int 3
```

There are a few ways to avoid this as mentioned in the comments:

1) Using invisible

```
lapply(1:3, function(x) invisible(x))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1

# [[2]]
# [1] 2

# [[3]]
# [1] 3

unlist(lapply(1:3, function(x) invisible(x)))
# [1] 1 2 3
```

2) Without explicitly printing inside the function

```
unlist(lapply(1:3, function(x) x))
# [1] 1 2 3
```

3) Assining the list to an object:

```
l1 <- lapply(1:3, function(x) print(x))
unlist(l1)
# [1] 1 2 3
```